# expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I made a validation change in one of my models, and it has made my tests fail. I altered one of my factories with the anticipation of having these fix my tests. Unfortunately my change fixed all of them but one, in which i'm getting the error, `expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0`

Ultimately I was working on a form and needed to have an input validated, so in my model I had.

```
validates :locations, presence: true
```

this ended up failing a test right here:

```
   describe "#create" do
    it 'sends an invitation if invite=yes' do
      delivery_count = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size

      expect{
        binding.pry
        post :create, coach: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:coach).merge(
          location: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:location)
        ), invite: 'yes'
        binding.pry
      }.to change(Coach, :count).by(1)

      d = Coach.last
      expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size).to eq (delivery_count + 1)
      last_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
      expect(last_email.to).to eq [d.email]
      expect(last_email.subject =~ /invitation instructions/).to be_truthy
    end
```

In my factory, the only thing that I changed was I moved this from an `after` to a `before`

```
  before :create do |coach|
    location = Location.first || create(:location)
    coach.locations << location
  end
```

Between where I have the two `binding.pry`s is where the count is supposed to add, and i'm not sure what I am missing to get this back up. If anyone could take a look, I would appreciate it for sure!

Comment: In your model you're validating presence of locations (plural) but in your POST request you're sending location (singular) parameter. It's hard to tell if this is a reason why it doesn't work, without knowing what associations your model has, but it looks bit strange.

Comment: @kdweber89, Can you post your code in  `coach.rb`?

Comment: if the location creation and assignment is happening in the `before` does that imply that the coach isn't persisited yet? Meaning it has nothing to be associated with yet. Without seeing the rest of that factory it's difficult to dig in much more than that.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to post more of my models, (I do have some sensitive info there that I can't let out.) But @IvanLučev you were exactly right on what was wrong with what I was doing. Thank you so much!